# d3 js sort error in chrome

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

I'm trying to sort d3 table on 2 tables and every browser does it ok except chrome. What problem can it be and how to fix it?

My code:

```
enter code her}).done( function (response) {
    response.sort(function(x, y){
        return d3.ascending(x.DQI_FROM_SPEC, y.DQI_FROM_SPEC);
    });
    response.sort(function(x, y){
        return d3.ascending(x.AREA, y.AREA);
    });e
```

Comment: The first sorting makes no sense, will be changed by the second one.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found a solution:
response.sort(function(x, y){
   return d3.ascending(x.AREA, y.AREA) || d3.ascending(x.DQI_FROM_SPEC, y.DQI_FROM_SPEC);
  });